# Give me an example of a differential operator that is normal, not self-adjoint and has application in Physics

Tags: operators, hilbert-space

I am looking for an example of a differential operator whose domain is the Hilbert space of square integrable functions with real $N$-dimensional domain $L^2(\mathbb R^N)$ having the following characteristics:

1. the operator is a linear combination of derivatives up to order 2;
2. the operator is normal, but not self-adjoint;
3. the operator's adjoint is known and is provided in the answer with an adjointness proof (or at least a sketch of the proof).
4. the operator has application in Physics (please, provide a sketch of the application).
5. the operator has non-trivial eigenfunctions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This post (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: [Crossposted on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390255/give-me-an-example-of-a-differential-operator-that-is-normal-not-self-adjoint-a#comment4931142_2390255)